# Tablespace and datafiles in Oracle

Tags: database, oracle

Is a Tablespace a data file that stores multiple tables, such as a compacted zip file, what is the relationship between tablespace and datafile, how are they organized and stored physically?

Comment: I do not think it's the same question, so I understood database, tablespace, datafiles are related more are still different. My question is specific to the file that stores the information and tablespace.

Comment: I can not exclude this question, people have invested time in answering it. This would be disrespectful. So I just voted to close the question, it's the only option I have.

Comment: Duplicate questions are not a mark against you. It just means the your question already has an answer on another question and you are being directed towards it like a roadsign. No need to delete your post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14220/physical.htm

Oracle stores data logically in tablespaces and physically in datafiles associated with the corresponding tablespace.

Databases, tablespaces, and datafiles are closely related, but they have important differences:

An Oracle database consists of one or more *logical storage units called tablespaces, which collectively store all of the database's data.*

*Each tablespace in an Oracle database consists of one or more files called datafiles, which are physical structures that conform to the operating system in which Oracle is running.*

*A database's data is collectively stored in the datafiles that constitute each tablespace of the database. For example, the simplest Oracle database would have one tablespace and one datafile. Another database can have three tablespaces, each consisting of two datafiles (for a total of six datafiles)*.

Comment: Even the simplest Oracle database has more than one tablespace: there's a data tablespace (e.g. USERS), a temporary tablespace for sorts, the SYSTEM for the data dictionary, the UNDO tablespace (for rollback) plus SYSAUX (since 10g) for other Oracle managed schemas.

Answer (score 2):

A Tablespace can have many data files associated. Tablespace is logical. Data Files are physical

Answer (score 2):

Tablespace corresponds to a logical area where oracle stores a collection of files that make up the database, datafiles are the physical files themselves.